# Is mime type really needed for playing video in HTML5?

Tags: html, video

I have a small snippet of code to play a video using HTML5. By accident, I discovered that it runs perfectly without a type attribute (the mime type) in my source element (see code below).

I thought that you always needed to provide the mime type, but apparently not. I've tried to google this, but with no luck. The code below works fine in both FireFox and Chrome. I have no other HTML5 supporting browsers installed. The video files used in my tests are local mp4 files and webm files using http. The result is the same; everything seemes to work fine without a mime type. Hence my question:

Is it perfectly safe to write this without the type attribute or did I miss anything here? (I don't need to support browsers older than IE11.)

Any information on the subject would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<video id="videoControl1" width="600" controls poster="somepic.png">
    <source id="videoSource1" src="somevideo.mp4"></source>
    <object>
        <p>Video is not supported</p>
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: Better safe than sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, browsers will detect the MIME type based on meta data and the incoming stream, I believe they do not even look at the file type anymore. You can see this in action by purposely renaming your video on a live webserver to the wrong extension, browsers and players will *usually* still play the video.

The only reference I could find on the subject is from a [tutorial site](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) (html5 rocks tutorials), quoting:

> In some cases, the browser won't play the video if the MIME type isn't
>   set properly.

This was written in 2010, and they said "in some cases". It should be safe not to provide a mime type, although providing the ***wrong*** one may or may not cause it not to play.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take my chances then and leave the mime type out.